# Wildfly deployment error in Linux with Spring Framework

Tags: linux, spring-mvc, cassandra, wildfly, kundera

I have been developing a web rest service with Spring framework supported by Kundera API for cassandra database. deployed in Wildfly runtime environment in Eclipse IDE.

I have externalised the persistence.xml and other property files in /standalone/configuration folder in Wildfly 10.1 directory.

It was working fine in Eclipse IDE runtime but when I deployed it in Actual server environment (CentOS),it shows error as file not found exception. When I looked it in the code, the error initiated in com.impetus.kundera.configure.MetamodelConfiguration. I have never worked with Wildfly or any application server.

I am using Spring MVC, not spring Boot and cannot use Spring Boot for some internal reasons.

While creating server in Eclipse, I have selected option for controlled by "Filesystem and shell operation" and server lifecycle is externally managed is unchecked.

```
04:29:39,260 INFO  [com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Loading Metadata from persistence.xml ...
04:29:39,261 INFO  [com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Loading Metadata from persistence.xml ...
04:29:39,272 INFO  [com.impetus.kundera.configure.PersistenceUnitConfiguration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Finishing persistence unit metadata configuration ...
04:29:39,278 INFO  [com.impetus.kundera.configure.MetamodelConfiguration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) No class to scan for persistence unit _pu. Entities will be loaded from classpath/ context-path
04:29:39,281 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.exivos.webclient.config.KunderaConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.impetus.kundera.classreading.ResourceReadingException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/web-client.war/WEB-INF/classes (No such file or directory)
04:29:39,282 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 106) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.exivos.webclient.config.KunderaConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.impetus.kundera.classreading.ResourceReadingException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content/web-client.war/WEB-INF/classes (No such file or directory
```